# create a new dataframe based on conditions from the existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I want to create a new dataframe with one column containing either 0 or 1 depending on the condition from the existing dataframe.

In df (existing) dataframe I want to check if values in columns a,b and c contain zeros simultaneously. If so, create a new dataframe with one column that returns zero if the condition is met. Otherwise return 1.

Example of existing dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0,1,0,0],"b":[0,None,0,None],"c":[0,8,0,10],"new_col":[5,5,5,5]})
mylist = ['a','b','c']

if any((df[mylist] == 0).all(1).values):
    print('all zeros')
else:
    print('contains nonzero')
```

I cannot figure out what should I put in place of print statements in order to get the desired results.

Desired dataframe:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'col':[0,1,0,1]})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need change condition for check not equal with `any`:

```
df['out'] = (df[mylist] != 0).any(1).astype(int)
print (df)
   a    b   c  new_col  out
0  0  0.0   0        5    0
1  1  NaN   8        5    1
2  0  0.0   0        5    0
3  0  NaN  10        5    1
```

If need new DataFrame:

```
df1 = (df[mylist] != 0).any(1).astype(int).to_frame('col')
print (df1)
   col
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
```

> It has to be using "if" statement

In pandas is use `if-else` function from `numpy` - [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['out'] = np.where((df[mylist] != 0).any(1), 1, 0)
print (df)
   a    b   c  new_col  out
0  0  0.0   0        5    0
1  1  NaN   8        5    1
2  0  0.0   0        5    0
3  0  NaN  10        5    1
```

Solution with `if-else` is also possible, but dont use it, because slow:

```
out = []

for x in (df[mylist] == 0).all(1).values:
    if np.any(x):
        out.append(0)
    else:
        out.append(1)

df['out'] = out
print (df)
   a    b   c  new_col  out
0  0  0.0   0        5    0
1  1  NaN   8        5    1
2  0  0.0   0        5    0
3  0  NaN  10        5    1
```